# XML Schema selector xsd xpath to node name

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have XML

```
<survey xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="a2.xsd">
    <question>
        <answer>
            <yes>Yes!!!</yes>
            <no>No...</no>
        </answer>
        <response>yes</response>
        <response>no</response>
    </question>
</survey>
```

And I need to match `response` value with any **node name** in `answer`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="survey">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="question">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="answer">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="yes" type="xsd:string" />
                                        <xsd:element name="no" type="xsd:string" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="response" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>

                    <xsd:keyref name="responseValidAnswerKeyRef" refer="validAnswerKey">
                        <xsd:selector xpath=".//response" />
                        <xsd:field xpath="." />
                    </xsd:keyref>
                    <xsd:key name="validAnswerKey">
                        <xsd:selector xpath=".//answer/*" />
                        <xsd:field xpath="???" />
                    </xsd:key>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

What should I write in `<xsd:field xpath="???" />` within `validAnswerKey` for fetching node names ("yes", "no", not values of them)?

**UPD1**

The real example.
I have list of interpreters, php, nodejs, etc. It looks like

```
<interpreters>
  <php>/usr/bin/php</php>
  <nodejs>/usr/bin/node</nodejs>
</interpreters>
```

and in the another node I need to choose this interpreter.

```
<interpreter_type>php</interpreter_type>
```

That's why I need a **node name**, instead value.

But yes, for the value dot (.) can be used only for **node value** and not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that each response is required to have the same value as one of the answers, I think you would want to give a field value of "." for validAnswerKey.

That makes the instance you show invalid, since "yes" is not the same string as either "Yes!!!" or "No...".

If by saying that each response must "match" an answer, you mean that after case-folding the response is required to be a prefix of the answer, then I don't think that the keyref construct is going to be much help:  it imposes a constraint that the value be the same as the value of a key, and there is no datatype in XSD for which "yes" and "Yes!!" map to the same value.

You might re-think your design, or you might try expressing the constraint you want with an XSD 1.1 assertion.

Comment: Yeah, with value of node it works, but I need name of node.
I have list of interpreters, php, nodejs, etc. It looks like `<interpreters><php>/usr/bin/php</php></interpreters>` and in the another node I need to choose this interpreter. `<interpreter_type>php</interpreter_type>`.